# foam pan + CBU = how to waterproof?

Tags: shower, waterproofing

I am renovating my master bathroom. In hand I have: a Trugard polystyrene pan and curb (essentially the same as Schluter-Kerdi), a Schluter drain flange, RedGard, and Hardiebacker board, plus items necessary for install (unmodded thinset, correct screws, etc).

I have resigned to needing membrane over the foam pan - but if I continue the membrane from the pan up a few inches to the backerboard, can I maintain the waterproofing by applying RedGard on the walls?

Comment: huh? redgard is membrane.

Comment: i meant, if i carried the kerdi membrane up a few inches, then continued up the Hardiebacker with Redgard

Comment: it's probably best not to mix two different brands of waterproofing, unless they specifically say they are compatible.